# Can I use for ... in syntax for angular models?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-in-loop

There is a `$scope.model` object in my controller. Its properties get fetched from my server on startup and  are bound to input fields in the view.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.name" placeholder="name"/>
<input type="email" ng-model="model.email" placeholder="email"/>
<!-- ... -->
```

When I want to loop over all properties of this model that came from either the server or the form fields. For example, I need this to find the properties that actually changed to only send those back to the server.

```
$scope.save = function() {
    // Filter changed properties
    var changed = {};
    for (i in $scope.model) {
        if (i in initial && model[i] == initial[i])
            continue;
        changed[i] = model[i];
    }

    // Send them to server
    // ...
}
```

However, I don't know whether AngularJS internally adds properties to my object. So is it safe to use this Syntax or would I loop over some AngularJS specific properties that I shouldn't see or even manipulate?

Comment: Dear downvoter, care to suggest improvement?

Comment: angularjs will bind property automatically no need  manual loop and also it will watch your object when its get change

Comment: Have you tried to check with `console.log( $scope.model )` to see if Angular has added anything to the object?

Comment: Although the reason why he wants to use `for .. in` may not be clear, it's an legitimate question.

Comment: @FrancisStalin I've edited the code to cover my real use case of using `for ... in`. If you are aware of a better way, please tell me!

Comment: angular.toJson(oldObj) == angular.toJson(newObj) you can compare the object like this, if any changes happen in the object u can hit the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular prefix its own stuff with `$` so if you want to be safe check that the key does not start with that.

If, for example, you're using `ng-repeat` angular WILL add a `$$hashKey` property.

And you'll never know if they'll start adding other properties in the future, but if they do they will (most likely) follow their convention with prefixing it.

```
$scope.save = function() {
    var changed = {};

    // Filter changed properties
    for (i in $scope.model) {
        // Skip Angular prefix
        if (i.length && i[0] == '$')
            continue;

        // Skip if not changed
        if (i in initial && model[i] == initial[i])
            continue;

        // Add to result
        changed[i] = model[i];
    }

    // Send them to server
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case angular does not add any new properties, so you can savely iterate over the properties.